# Building Xtext projects on Travis CI

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, travis-ci, xtext, tycho

I have an Xtext project created locally using the Eclipse wizard. When I try to build it in Travis CI using `mvn clean install`, it fails with the following error: 

`An unexpected error occured while launching the test runtime (return code 13).`

The build works locally, which makes me think that there is some eclipse specific package that is missing.

What external packages do I need installed on the machine to be able to build Xtext project in a CI server like Travis?

Comment: do you start travis with xvfb https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-xvfb-to-Run-Tests-That-Require-a-GUI

Comment: Can you paste your Travis configuration and the whole stack trace?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich that was the reason, after adding
 before_install:
  - "Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1360x1024x24 &"
  - "export DISPLAY=:1"

the problem was resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Travis with Xvfb to be able to execute ui tests. https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-xvfb-to-Run-Tests-That-Require-a-GUI